# Can I play Gods and Kings now that Brave New World is out?

Tags: civilization-5

If I buy the Brave New World DLC, can I still play the game as it was with Gods & Kings?  Or will all the games now include the new Brave New World features?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Although Steam will automatically download all DLC for the game, you can go into your settings inside Civ V itself and turn DLC content off, such as the expansion packs.

Additionally, the UI should now revert to whatever version you're playing as well, as of [the latest patch](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?247316-New-patch-is-live).